# Android Firebase Realtime "DatabaseDefault FirebaseApp is not initialized"

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to connect to Firebase realtime DB from android.

SDK Version 29

```
public void init(Context context)
{
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://xxxx.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference();
```

I get the error:

Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.xxx.xxxx. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

firebase.json is

```
{
  "database": {
"rules": "secrules.json"
  }
}
```

secrules.json is

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1619046000000",  // 2021-4-22
    ".write": "now < 1619046000000",  // 2021-4-22
  }
}
```

build gradle module app level is

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')

    // Declare the dependency for the Realtime Database library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
```

build gradle project level is

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I've tried to follow latest guidelines and a few suggestions in stack overflow with no difference.

Project was initialised from the firebase console. I'm not using an emulator database.

Comment: Are you adding a secondary database in addition to the default?

Comment: I'm not adding a secondary database at the moment, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary firebase projects and related assets including database are initialized automatically, no need to specify anything, just add **google services json** to project. If for some reason you need to initialize it, best place is the class extending Application.

```
public ZAONE extends Application {

public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
}}
```

And then add that class to the manifest. A good resource is here, documentation  on [setting up on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Brilliant, works thanks! I followed your guide link, watched the video. I registered my app in the online firebase console, installed the google services json file. I also switched android test devices to one that had a playstore icon and I added the google-services' plugin line to the module app build grade. All in that video

Comment: I'm glad it worked. That is the beauty of stackoverflow.